# How to detect multiline strings in VS Code Extension

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I had been trying to match multiline string and character literals in VS Code, but there is no support for highlighting across more than one line using a regex. [This is a known issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate/issues/41) At the bottom of the issue, it is told to use a semantic highlight provider.

VS Code's [Semantic highlight guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide) gives a set number of tokens to semantically highlight. My main problem is that multiline strings are not detected as tokens in the first place, so they cannot be modified to change to the right color.

I am trying to match a BQN string: A BQN string is a double quote, followed by any number of non-quote characters including newlines, followed by another double quote. Double quotes inside a string are escaped by typing two quotes: `"qu""ote"` translates to `qu"ote`.

I'd like to know if there is a way to syntax highlight multiline strings via this method or any other method available to a VS Code extension. Help and examples are highly appreciated.

Comment: multi line strings in python are displayed with the TextMate Scope `string`

Comment: Can you point me to a file where this is used? @rioV8

Comment: probably the `ms-python` extension